# How do i change the location directory of python open document?

Tags: python, path, directory

i was just wondering how i can change the location/directory that python uses to navigate and open files.

I am a super noob so please use small words if you help me, and if you do, thanks.

In case it matter, i use two mass storage devices one is located under the A:\ and the other using the default C:.  From memory i installed python under the A drive even though i know some parts are under the C drive. I also believe that i have set my mass storage devices up in AHCI or IDE.

Example Code:

```
File_Test = open("Test.txt", "r")
```

This then produces the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>    File_Test = open("Test.txt", "r")
>   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Test.txt'"

Which from what i understand is python can't find the directory under which thise file is located.

I would really like to know how to make python locate files in my specified directory. If you can help i would be very appreciative, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `os.chdir()` function.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/username'
>>> os.chdir(r'/home/username/Downloads')
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/username/Downloads'
```

You can get the current working directory using the `os.getcwd` function. The `os.chdir` function changes the current working directory to some other directory that you specify. (one which contains your file) and then you can open the file using a normal `open(fileName, 'r')` call.

Comment: Thankyou so, so, so much. I owe you big time and you helped so fast, thankyou :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think the answer was too terse. An explanation of what `os.chdir` does and why it is necessary would be useful.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks. Added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

More precisely, the problem is that there is no file "Test.txt" in the directory Python considers its *current working directory*. You can see which directory that is by calling `os.getcwd`. There are two solutions.

First, you can change Python's working directory by calling `os.chdir` to be the directory where your file lives. (This is what Sukrit's answer alludes to.)

```
import os
# Assuming file is at C:\some\dir\Test.txt
os.chdir("C:\some\dir")
file_test = open("Test.txt", "r")
```

Second, you can simply pass the full, absolute path name to `open`:

```
file_test = open("C:\some\dir\Test.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you have helped me understand Sukrits answer a bit more. For instance the os.getcwd, the "cwd" in that function is, if i am correct the initials standing for current working directory. Thankyou for making sense of his answer and providing more help :)